# Replace char at position in each element

Tags: python, list, replace, readfile

I have a txt file filled with data, I want to write each line of my text to elements of a list called `DATA` in Python, each line/element looks like this:

```
data[0] = EPH21 2017-05-05T00:30    2375.50 2376.50 2375.50 2376.50 712 0
data[1] = EPH21 2017-05-05T01:00    2376.50 2376.75 2375.50 2375.75 821 0
data[2] = EPH21 2017-05-05T01:30    2376.00 2376.00 2374.75 2375.25 1453 0
```

I want to modify each line/element to have `","` instead of spaces, so it looks like a CSV file.
Also I want to replace the `"T"` contained in the timestamps with `",`" as well.
In the end I want to write the modified list into a new text file.

After the changes I want my list to look like this:

```
data[0] = EPH21,2017-05-05,00:30,2375.50,2376.50,2375.50,2376.50,712,0
data[1] = EPH21,2017-05-05,01:00,2376.50,2376.75,2375.50,2375.75,821,0
data[2] = EPH21,2017-05-05,01:30,2376.00,2376.00,2374.75,2375.25,1453,0
```

How can I do this?
I tried with this code but no luck so far:

```
file = open("EPH21_30 Minutes.txt", "r")
data = []
for line in file:
    data.append(line)
    
for element in data:
    element.replace(" ", ",")
    element.replace("T", ",")

MyFile = open('output.txt','w')
for element in data:
    MyFile.write(element)
    MyFile.write('\n')
MyFile.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. `str.replace` returns the new vlaue, it doesn't change the original string.

So the problem is this part:

```py
for element in data:
    element.replace(" ", ",")
    element.replace("T", ",")
```

Keeping your structure, it should be something like:

```py
result = []
for element in data:
    tmp = element.replace(" ", ",")
    tmp = tmp.replace("T", ",")
    result.append(tmp)
```

Shorted solution: use list comprehensions:

```py
with open("EPH21_30 Minutes.txt", "r") as file:
    data = [line.replace(" ", ",").replace("T", ",") for line in file]

with open('output.txt','w') as MyFile:
    for element in data:
        MyFile.write(element)
        MyFile.write('\n')
```

[I also used `with` to automatically close files because you don't seem to close the input file.]

Comment: Beat me to it :-)

Comment: thanks you are the best, it works perfectly!